# Передача строки из одной html страницы на другую (не по Url)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Здравствуйте. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как передать строку с одной html-страницы на другую при нажатии на кнопку "Перейти на др стр" так, чтобы передаваемый параметр не был виден в url-строке.

Разрабатываю Progressive Web App с помощью Firebase и компонентов Polymer на JavaScript. Страницы содержат `dom-module polymer`.

Пока передаю вот так:

1. На одной странице: `document.location = "/page2?id=" + this.noteId;`
2. На второй странице получаем строку: `var paramValue =
   window.location.href.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];`

Но переданный параметр виден в url-строке. Читала, что можно использовать элементы `iron-ajax` и `iron-request`, но не могу понять, как их использовать и получать на другой странице переданные параметры.

Comment: Я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону cookie или localSorage. Например перед перенаправлением пользователя на другую страницу устанавливать в хранилище переменную 
localStorage.setItem('id', 1234);
a на принимающей странице её соответственно считывать 
localStorage.getItem('id);

В рамках iron есть компонент https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-localstorage

Comment: Спасибо, помогло добиться желаемого с помощью localStorage.setItem и getItem.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме localstorage вы можете ещё использовать sessionstorage(данные удаляются при окончании сессии) ,  а также можете использовать indexedDB, если объем данных большой.
Как вариант, вы можете записывать в свойства компонента данные, например :

```
<some-element prop="property_value"> </some-element>
```

А в Web-componte some-element :

```
Class SomeElement... 
Static get properties () {
return {
 prop: {
    type:Object, 
    value: {}
           }
      }
}
```

Вообще, способ реализации зависит оттого, чего вы хотите достичь